# Get PowerView to work with existing cubes on SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sharepoint, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012, olap-cube, powerview

I've been doing some research into the setup required to get PowerView to connect to existing cubes sitting on a SQL Server 2008 R2 instance. Can anyone confirm that the following is right (or correct me if I'm wrong)?

I believe I need the following:

- SharePoint Server 2010 Enterprise Edition with 'Reporting Services Add-in for SharePoint Products' installed from SQL Server 2012 or SQL Server 2008 R2
- My existing SQL Server Analysis Services 2008 R2 Enterprise Edition running in 'SharePoint Integrated' mode
- SQL Server 2012 Reporting Services installed in 
  'SharePoint Integrated' mode updated with SQL Server 2012 Service Pack 1 Cumulative Update 4

I have been trying to put together the information I have found in the following places:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/95a31c10-f558-48b1-ab1f-ee7cf56741e9/powerview-along-with-sql-server-2008-r2?forum=sqlreportingservices

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/analysisservices/archive/2013/05/31/power-view-connectivity-for-multidimensional-models-released.aspx

but it's extremely possible I may be getting things confused.

Comment: did you succeed in connecting power view with SQL Server 2008 cubes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create Power View reports the data source needs to be hosted on

- SQL Server Analysis Services 2012 RTM for Tabular models
- SQL Server Analysis Services 2012 CU4 for [Multidimensional models](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/analysisservices/archive/2013/05/31/power-view-connectivity-for-multidimensional-models-released.aspx)